# Hide nav and title on specific template ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a ionic app and I want no `nav` or `title` for the login page. I have worked out to remove the title with ..

```
<ion-view title="Login" hide-nav-bar="true" >
<ion-content padding="true" has-header="false">
```

but the nav at the bottom still stays on the screen

[image]

```
fooSync.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
{
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login')

...

$stateProvider.state('login',
{
    url: '/login',
    views:
    {
        settings:
        {
            templateUrl: 'login.html'
        }
    }
})
})
```

Comment: Share your. config code. You have used ui-router's child view to create your login page. Thats why the *tabs* are showing.

Comment: I have added the code as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login state must not be inside a `view`. Those tabs are coming from the `settings` view. You just simple need to remove that.

```
$stateProvider.state('login',
       {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html'            
       }
 })
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: urgghhhh what a dope. thats what ya get for cut and pasteing